Flutter: Missing ManeuverView ID After first Attempts
I’m using both the flutter_mapbox_navigation: ^0.2.2 and mapbox_maps_flutter: ^0.6.0 packages in my Flutter project, and I’m facing a strange runtime crash that occurs after first attempts to use the navigation feature. The app works perfectly the first times I try it, but on the second attempt, it crashes with the following error:
Error
E/AndroidRuntime( 6401): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 6401): Process: app.splenify.nurses, PID: 6401
E/AndroidRuntime( 6401): java.lang.NullPointerException: Missing required view with ID: app.splenify.nurses:id/maneuverView
E/AndroidRuntime( 6401):    at com.mapbox.navigation.dropin.databinding.MapboxManeuverGuidanceLayoutBinding.bind(MapboxManeuverGuidanceLayoutBinding.java:60)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6401):    at com.mapbox.navigation.dropin.maneuver.ManeuverViewBinder.bind(ManeuverViewBinder.kt:27)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6401):    at com.mapbox.navigation.dropin.maneuver.ManeuverViewBinder.bind(ManeuverViewBinder.kt:16)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6401):    at com.mapbox.navigation.ui.base.lifecycle.UICoordinator$onAttached$1$invokeSuspend$$inlined$collect$1.emit(Collect.kt:136)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6401):    at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ZipKt$combine$$inlined$combineUnsafe$FlowKt__ZipKt$1$2.invokeSuspend(Zip.kt:262)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6401):    at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ZipKt$combine$$inlined$combineUnsafe$FlowKt__ZipKt$1$2.invoke(Unknown Source:13)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6401):    at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ZipKt$combine$$inlined$combineUnsafe$FlowKt__ZipKt$1$2.invoke(Unknown Source:6)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6401):    at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.CombineKt$combineInternal$2.invokeSuspend(Combine.kt:76)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6401):    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6401):    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6401):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6401):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6401):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:263)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6401):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8292)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6401):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6401):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:612)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6401):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6401):    Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@4521ef7, Dispatchers.Main]
I/Process ( 6401): Sending signal. PID: 6401 SIG: 9

Additionally, I’ve noticed the following message on mobile notification:
4 retained objects, tap to dump heap. App visible, waiting until 5 retained objects in notification
Code
class TurnByTurnNavigationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TurnByTurnNavigationScreen({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<TurnByTurnNavigationScreen> createState() =>
      _TurnByTurnNavigationScreenState();
}

class _TurnByTurnNavigationScreenState
    extends State<TurnByTurnNavigationScreen> {
  MapServiceController mapServiceController = MapServiceController.instence;
  NurseController nurseController = NurseController.instence;
  PatientController patientController = PatientController.instence;
  List<PatientModify> sortedPatients = [];
  List<WayPoint> wayPoints = <WayPoint>[];
  MapBoxNavigationViewController? _controller;
  late MapBoxOptions _navigationOption;
  bool _isNavigating = false;

  Future<void> initialize() async {
    if (!mounted) return;
    // Sort patients by distance
    sortedPatients = calculateDistancesAndSort(
      patientController.patientsModify,
      nurseController.currentNurseLatLog.latitude,
      nurseController.currentNurseLatLog.longitude,
    );

    // Add nurse location as the first waypoint
    wayPoints.add(
      WayPoint(
        name: "You",
        latitude: nurseController.currentNurseLatLog.latitude,
        longitude: nurseController.currentNurseLatLog.longitude,
        isSilent: false,
      ),
    );

    // Add patient waypoints
    for (int i = 0; i < sortedPatients.length; i++) {
      wayPoints.add(
        WayPoint(
          name: sortedPatients[i].name,
          latitude: sortedPatients[i].latitude,
          longitude: sortedPatients[i].longitude,
          isSilent: false,
        ),
      );
    }

    _navigationOption = MapBoxNavigation.instance.getDefaultOptions();
    _navigationOption.mode = MapBoxNavigationMode.driving;
    _navigationOption.allowsUTurnAtWayPoints = true;
    _navigationOption.longPressDestinationEnabled = false;
    _navigationOption.simulateRoute = false;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initialize();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    MapBoxNavigation.instance.finishNavigation();
    _controller?.dispose();
    wayPoints.clear();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _startMultiStopNavigation() async {
    if (_isNavigating) return;
    _isNavigating = true;
    await MapBoxNavigation.instance.startNavigation(
      wayPoints: wayPoints,
      options: _navigationOption,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1,
        child: MapBoxNavigationView(
          options: _navigationOption,
          onCreated: (controller) async {
            _controller = controller;

            if (!_isNavigating) {
              await _startMultiStopNavigation();
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


